# Ansible get_url has error: url_open error

Tags: php, ansible, phpunit, ubuntu-18.04

I try to download phpUnit via Ansible.
Here is part of code:

```
  tasks:
  - name: Install phpUnit
    get_url:
      url: http://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.5.phar
      dest: /usr/local/bin/
      mode: 0555
    become: true
```

...end result is:

```
    {
       "changed":false,
       "dest":"/usr/local/bin/",
       "gid":1000,
       "group":"developer",
       "mode":"0755",
       "msg":"Request failed: ",
       "owner":"developer",
       "size":4096,
       "state":"directory",
       "uid":1000,
       "url":"http://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar"
    }
```

If I try to download it via a browser or Ubuntu wget it works.
Is anybody has any idea what could be the problem.
There is no proxy behind ...but I am interested in what would be if there would be a proxy behind...

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to increase the verbosity of the run, because `"Request failed: "` doesn't help; we'll need to see if there is some extra information that help figure it out

Comment: Hello Metthew! Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it out and write feedback! Thanks it again!

Comment: So yes, your traceback confirms it is related to the proxy; we can't figure out your proxy on S.O., so you'll need to consult with some of your local configuration to figure it out